# Are there any established performance benchmarks for spark-sql expressions with time analysis?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, performance-testing

I want to understand is there a well-established framework to understand how the analysis time grows with the complexity of a spark-sql expression. How long of an expression can be fed to spark after which it starts degrading its performance.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what kind of expressions?

Comment: Let's say we have a spark-sql expression that has a regex containing 4000 characters combined with multiple smaller predicates using AND/OR etc. Will spark face any issues while handling an expression this long? Can it even analyze it, let alone execute it?